# Using methods of a parent class in PyQt5

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, pyqt5

Let's say we have imported: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton`.

and we have created a class which inherits from QWidgets:

```
class mainwindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.createUI()
    def createUI():
```

If we write this : `act1 = QAction("close",self)` inside our class,
can we say that we are using a method(QAction in this case) which is present in the parent class(QWidget)?? 
If yes, why don't we call the parent class name before the method name like this: `act1 = QWidget.QAction("close",self)`?

As far as i know when we want to use a method or attribute of a parent class inside our child class we will have to call the parent class name before the name of the method or attribute.

Comment: `QAction` is _not_ a method of the `QWidget` class. It is a subclass of `QObject`.

Comment: @bnaecker so Qwidget itself inherits from QObject?

Comment: It does, but I don't see how that's relevant. You can't do this: `QWidget.QAction`. That doesn't mean anything, because `QAction` is not a method defined in the `QWidget` class. It is an [is-a relationship](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php), not a has-a relationship.

Comment: @bnaecker but in order to be able to use the QAction subclass, our class needs to inherit from QWidget.

Comment: No, that's not correct. _Any_ C++ class can _have_ a `QAction` as a member variable. By inheriting from `QWidget`, you get several methods already defined for you, if that's what you mean. But again, I'm not sure how that's relevant to your question. `QAction` is not a method of the `QWidget` class. It is an entirely separate class, with no direct inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, QAction is not a method of the class QWidget, as @bnaecker pointed out already.

Furthermore, you don't need to call methods of you parent class explicitly if they are not overriden by the child class. The interpreter automaticly does that for you.

Comment: So what is exactly happening when we say `act1 = QAction()`? Are we creating an instance of the class QAction?

Comment: Exactly - it creates an instance.

Comment: Btw: If you call a method within an instance (the instance calls it'd own method) the call starts (in almost all cases) with self, e.g. self.foo()

Comment: So we are using a class(QAction) inside another class (let's say, our main window class), right? and in order for us to use QAction in our class, it has to inherit from QWidget or else the interpreter wouldn't know where QAction came from despite importing it at the beggining of our code. Is this correct?

Comment: The interpreter will only know what the name `QAction` refers to if you import it. As in, `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction`.

Comment: We are using a class inside another class, that's right. But there is no need for any of those two classes to inherit from each other. As you pointed out, the import at the beginning does the trick here. Since you imported QAction at the beginning, the interpreter knows that QAction is a class for the whole file as long as you do not define a variable called QAction.

Comment: That concept is called "scoping", see here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Comment: @bnaecker Thanks! I got it now: our class should inherit from QWidget if we want to use some methods like `setGeometry()` for our class, and whether it inherits from QWidget or not, we will still be able to use QAction in our class as long as we are importing it.

Comment: Yep, you got it!

Answer (score 0):

You don't use parent class for these cases.